# The correct way to handle observables and interrupt them in RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a code like this:

Process X:

```
   getLocationObservable() // ---> async operation the fetches the location. 
    //  Once location is found(or failed to find) it sends it to this filter :
            .filter(location -> {
                --- Operation A ---
                after finishing the operation A, I either return 'true' and continue 
                 to the next observable which is a Retrofit server call, or simply 
                  return 'false' and quit.
            })
            .flatMap(location -> getRetrofitServerCallObservable( location )
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    new Observer<MyCustomResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                            _disposable = d;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(MyCustomResponse response) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {

                        }
                    });
```

In the Location class it's like this :

```
 private PublishSubject<Location> locationPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    public Observable<Location> getLocationObservable() {
        return locationPublishSubject;
    }

    and then...
    locationPublishSubject.onNext( foundLocation );
```

the getLocationObservable is based on a PublishSubject, that returns the Location via onNext.

My goal is to have complete control of the whole Process X. That means : no matter if it's currently fetching the location in getLocationObservable, or if it's doing Operation A inside the filter, or if it doing the RetrofitCall observable - once a user clicks on something, I want to stop/cancel/interrupt whatever it is doing. Because otherwise that will lead to unpredictable behavior, and would end up fatal.

**How do I achieve this, while making sure I don't have issues(such as memory leak issues, etc.) ?**

**Will calling "dispose()" on the reference called "_disposable"(as stated in the code above) achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating CompositeDisposable() and add your observable to it in your onSubscribed() call. Then if the user clicks anywhere on screen, you can just call `compositeDisposable.clear()`
to interrupt whatever operation is going on under that observable.

Also, as you are already assigning io() & mainThread() to your base observable, you dont need to assign the same in the flatMap. The new observable will follow those from parent observable.

Comment: Actually I added the io() and mainThread() to the flatMap cause I was getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.. so it seems I need it..

If I do `clear()` on the composite disposible, will it also interrupt the operation inside `filter`? I mean, this operation isn't an observable after all, just a sync operation. Will it terminate it?

Also, do I need to call dispose/clear only in onDestroy of the activity? or after every Process X ?

Comment: Clearing the disposable instance of your Observable will terminate whatever tasks you have  running under that observable. Most of the times we put the code to update ui elements in our onNext or onComplete methods. At that point, if your activity is destroyed and your observable flow tries to update the ui, then it will throw IllegleStateException. That is why, you should always consider calling compositeDisposable.clear() at onDestroy() call of your activity/fragment

Comment: it doesn't seem to work.. I placed a for-loop inside the `filter`, printing some log.. and even though `compositeDiposable.clear()` occurred, the loop kept running until the `if` statement was finished. Moreover - it even executed the retrofit observable that came after the filter